# SSH2 in PHP to connect to remote server

Tags: php

I'm using the following code to connect locally using SSH2, but I'm trying to work out how public/private keys are handled when connecting to a remote server.

```
$SSH_CONNECTION = ssh2_connect('localhost', 22, array('hostkey'=>'ssh-rsa'));
ssh2_auth_pubkey_file($SSH_CONNECTION, 'username','/path/to/id_rsa.pub','/path/to/id_rsa')
```

If I'm connecting to a remote server, does there need to be a key file (public or private?) on the remote server, and how do I reference it? I'm not sure if the code is the same or exactly how it works.

Appreciate any explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the remote server to accept the keys, you need to put a copy of the public key in a file called `authorized_keys` in the `.ssh` directory in the home folder of the user you are logging in as.

So to authenticate as `bob` on a remote server, you would have a file called `authorized_keys` in `/home/bob/.ssh` on the remote with the public key in it (e.g. `ssh-rsa AAAA..<long-string-of-text>..cXrTp bob@host`) (you can have more than one authorized keys, each one goes on it's own line in the file).

The `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` files need to be on the client system where you call [`ssh2_auth_pubkey_file`](http://php.net/ssh2_auth_pubkey_file) and readable by your PHP script.

This article about [SSH Keys](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys) gives a good explanation about how to generate a keypair for key based authentication and how you can transfer the key to the host as well.

Without the public key in the `authorized_keys` file for the user you are trying to authenticate as, the authentication will not work.

Also, be sure to take the necessary security precautions by protecting the private key with a passphrase, making the private key unreadble by other users on the system, and protecting the passphrase in your script or controlling access to the file your script will read it from if it will be stored.

Comment: Ok thanks I'll read the article. So if the public key file must be on the server being SSH'd to, must the private key be on the server you're SSHing from?

Comment: i.e. `/path/to/id_rsa.pub` is the path on the remote server and `/path/to/id_rsa` is the path on the local server?

Comment: `id_rsa.pub` (public key) and `id_rsa` (private key) both are on the server you are SSH'ing from, and the contents of id_rsa.pub goes in the `authorized_keys` file on the remote server.  When you generate a keypair, both the public and private get created in the .ssh folder on the client, which is what you would point your PHP SSH client to.

Comment: If you're not sure where to put the public key, you can use the `ssh-copy-id` utility. (included with the ssh client these days) Generate the keypair on your local machine, then run `ssh-copy-id username@the_host_you_want` - after you give the password, the key will be copied in the right place.